# How can I bind data to a wpf combobox to give me a display and data value?

Tags: wpf, powershell, data-binding

I searched for hours to find a solution to the requirement below. I've found a number of articles but none make clear how you do this using wfp forms and PowerShell. I've tried to translate the examples I found that used Win forms and/or C# without success.

I have a two dimension arraylist that contains DisplayText and LinkText. The array will be dynamically created so I don't want to hard code the values anywhere.

What I want to do is display the combo box that displays the DisplayText but uses the associated value of LinkText when a selection is made.

I've read up on data binding and have a bit of an understanding of how it works; and hope it will become clearer as I use it.

My test code is as below.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$BoxItems = @(@{Display = 'Google'; Link = 'https://www.google.com/'},@{Display = 'Yahoo'; Link = 'https://yahoo.com/'},@{Display = 'MSN'; Link = 'https://www.msn.com/'})
$BoxList = @()
foreach ($bi in $BoxItems) {
    $BoxListItem = new-object System.Object
    $BoxListItem | add-member -type NoteProperty -name Display -value $BoxItems[$i].Display
    $BoxListItem | add-member -type NoteProperty -name Link -value $BoxItems[$i].Link
    $BoxList += $BoxListItem
}  

$WPFcbotest.ItemsSource = $BoxList
$WPFcbotest.DisplayMemberPath = $BoxList.Display
$WPFcbotest.SelectedValuePath = $BoxList.Link

$MainForm.ShowInTaskbar = $true
$MainForm.ShowDialog() > $null
```

Because I've tried, psCustomObjects, hashtables and arrays as a data source I'm no longer convinced I'm even using one method but maybe a mix up.

The current code shows a form with a combo box with 3 blank options.

I'd appreciate any direction or solution to get this sorted in the simplest way possible please.

Comment: Looking at this I'm not even sure why I'm creating an array from the arraylist! I'm guessing it is as a result of trying a concoction of various suggestions and methods I found.
Totally confused about this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I went back to the multiple sites I'd collected in my favourites on this topic. I figured the best option was https://powerintheshell.com/2015/12/05/psgui-binding-examples/ by David das Neves.

I noticed his example used a process object, so I cast my arraylist to type  PSCustomObject.

I tidied up my code as below and tested.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$BoxItems = @([PSCustomObject]@{Display = 'Google'; Link = 'https://www.google.com/'},[PSCustomObject]@{Display = 'Yahoo'; Link = 'https://yahoo.com/'},[PSCustomObject]@{Display = 'MSN'; Link = 'https://www.msn.com/'})  

$WPFcbotest.ItemsSource = $BoxItems 
$WPFcbotest.DisplayMemberPath = 'Display'
$WPFcbotest.SelectedValuePath = 'Link'

$MainForm.ShowInTaskbar = $true
$MainForm.ShowDialog() > $null
```

$wpfcbotest.SelectedValue now returns the link value to the corresponding display value.

The above works for me but is not the entry into data binding I thought I'd be making. If anyone has another method I'd be interested to see it.